# Koala is not runing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am very new to linux. I have downloaded koala sass  64bit for ubuntu from the official site. Its installed successfully. But when i tries to run it it didn't start. I have already tried this solution which doesn't worked for me.
https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Unable-to-run-Koala-in-Linux.
my os: 18.04lts

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this thing, simply downloaded binary [from official site](http://koala-app.com/).

At first install Koala (as normal user):

```
sudo apt install git npm ruby ruby-dev libgconf-2-4

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/oklai/koala/releases/download/v2.3.0/koala_2.3.0_x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xf koala_2.3.0_x86_64.tar.gz
usr/share/koala/Koala
```

It launches normally:

[image: Koala]

but I do not how to test it further.

Answer (score 1):

Just install libgconf2-4

```
$sudo apt -y install libgconf2-4
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on Pop_OS 20.04 but the steps here did: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libgconf-2-4